# Multiple Iterations from One Response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, single-page-application

I want to show a list of product with details and a list of product's models which is checked at detailed list but I want to do it with only one get request. I mean I will get the json of products and I will use multiple times in page.

Here is my product list with details:

```
<div class="box-content" ng-controller="PostsCtrl" ><div>
<input type="search" ng-model="search"></div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable dataTable" id="DataTables_Table_0" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><tags:label text="productid"/></th>
<th><tags:label text="main.category"/></th>
<th><tags:label text="sub.category"/></th>
<th><tags:label text="brand"/></th>
<th><tags:label text="model"/></th>
<th><tags:label text="sku"/></th>
<th><tags:label text="active"/></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="actionresult{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search">
    <td>{{post.productid}}</td>
    <td>{{post.subcategory}}</td>
    <td>{{post.subcategoryid}}</td>
    <td>{{post.brand}}</td>
    <td>{{post.model}}</td>
    <td>{{post.brandid}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-checked="post.isactive"></td>
    </tr>
```

List of models:

```
<ul ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:checked">{{post.model}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my controller:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

    app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('http://localhost/admin.productss/searchwithjson').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.posts = data;

        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    });
    </script>
```

I think that the way I do above; I do 2 request. I can't list checked models too.

How can I modify my code ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just use the same data in both spots... ?

Comment: Actually I ask how to use same data in both lists. I am very new at angular.

Comment: so both of your HTML are in different controllers. Am i right. If so, use a service to make a `http call` and populate `posts ` array and use between controllers. If not, you can use the `posts` array wherever you want inside the enabled controller

Comment: As @AlhuckA pointed out, I'm assuming they're in the same controller (since not controller was specified in your table). If that's the case, I don't see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/o1xn7hmc/

Comment: I updated question. I use same controller for both list.

Comment: so your code looks good !!! What is your exact problem so that we can help?

Comment: I think If I use posts data for each iterations I do get request too. May be I am wrong. So I want to get json one time and use it multiple times wherever I want. 

I want to list the models which is checked at detailed list.

Comment: From the edit you posted, your HTML is using two separate instances of the controller, so yes there will be two requests. You need to put the HTML for each one inside the same HTML element where the controller is declared.

Comment: Conceptually, "an HTTP request can return 'anything you want.'"  If you want to return "both information about a product and a list of model-numbers," you're free to do so.  Just specify that the "list of model numbers" is one of the attributes of the product-information that this request returns.  Once you get that data, on the javascript side, simply store it somewhere convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

put both of the elements descending the same element using the controller:

```
<div class="box-content" ng-controller="PostsCtrl" >

    ...Some other html....

    <table>
        <tr id="actionresult{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search">
            <td>{{post.productid}}</td>
            <td>{{post.subcategory}}</td>
            <td>{{post.subcategoryid}}</td>
            <td>{{post.brand}}</td>
            <td>{{post.model}}</td>
            <td>{{post.brandid}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="post.checked"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    ...Some other html....

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts |  filter:{checked:true}">{{post.model}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Option 2:**

in the controller cache the request:

```
app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
  $rootScope.cache = $rootScope.cache || {};

  if(!$rootScope.cache.posts){
      $http.get('http://localhost/admin.productss/searchwithjson').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.cache.posts = $scope.posts = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
  } else {
      $scope.posts = $rootScope.cache.posts;
  }
});
```

Comment: How about list of checked models ?

Comment: The list of checked models is there in Option 1. At the bottom.

Comment: first of all, did it help solving the double request issue?

Comment: I think you need to change  ng-model="checked" to  ng-model="post.checked",  

and also change filter:checked to filter:'checked'

Comment: Yes, it helps to solve double request issue.

Can you edit your answer for models list. I tried what you said but it shows nothing now.

Comment: Just edited. hope I helped, and if you could pls set answer as corrct one.

Comment: Now it nearly works, initially doesn't work. I mean, at first, list of models doesn't seems but after marking checkboxes it works.

Comment: Well you need to iterate over the posts once you get them from the server, and set there checked property true

Comment: Can you update your answer now and please can you explain why you set   ng-model="post.checked" and filter:{checked:true} so it worked ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77688/discussion-between-gariptipici-and-molow).